# Workbench vs Report: same user, different number of records viewed

Tags: reporting, opportunity-lineitem, workbench

When I run a **report** on the OpportunityLineItems in my org I can read a total of **38517** records at the end of the page.
If I check it on the **Workbench** the result is of **38316** (-201) OpportunityLineItems. Why?

Notes:

1. there are no filters on the report (note that I see more records on the report than on workbench).
2. There are no Territories or Roles set on the report.
3. The Report Type that I used is a custom one including Projects, Opportunity, Products.

Comment: I would look for an example of a missing record, and look for something different about it.

Comment: I think it's a good idea... but I don't know how much time it could take. I could view from 1 to 38316 contacts! :)

Comment: If you export both lists to Excel, you can match them against each other with VLOOKUP. I'm a little confused by your reference to Contacts. Aren't these OpportunityLineItems?

Comment: Sorry, it's OpportunityLineItems. Anyway, I didn't know it was possible to export the records through the report too. I'll try. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue.

If an Opportunity has 4 OpportunityLineItems in the report there are 4 rows.
If an Opportunity has 1 OpportunityLineItem in the report there is 1 row.
If an Opportunity has 0 OpportunityLineItems in the report there is still 1 row!

In the workbench I see the number of OpportunityLineItems.
In the report I see the number of opportunityLineItems + the number of Opportunities not having OpportunityLineItems (201 in my case).